# How to find out what middlewares are used?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I've inherited a codebase that I'm trying to prune - looking at middlewares I see some that I can't see being used in routes, nor controllers, but I'm worried that I'm not taking into account all scenarios.

For example - there's this middleware: `'2fa' => \PragmaRX\Google2FALaravel\Middleware::class` that I can't see being used anywhere, yet when I comment it, our 2fa functionality fails to work.

As such, the question is - is there a way to see where given middlewares are used?

PS. I'm talking here purely about middlewares references within `$routeMiddleware` array

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of all the routes in your application, with the middleware applied

Go to your project root and write in

```
php artisan route:list
```

if it's too many records, use grep

```
php artisan route:list | grep "fa"
```

if It's not being applied to the routes file, try viewing in the controllers or the `RouteServiceProvider`

Edit:
If your project is using its facade, you can try and search for `use Google2FA` in your project

Comment: The routes where 2fa functionality is used don't display `2fa` middleware in route:list

Comment: search in the RouteServiceProvider or the Login controllers (or where it's possible to being used). Try searching for the edit that I've placed aswell. If after that you still can't find it, then it's being used somewhere else it (in my opinion) shouldn't be and to find that out, search for the name of the middleware. It's not a ghost, it exists somewhere

Comment: I agree, it will certainly exist somewhere, however I was hoping for a generic method not requiring me to check all middlewares and finding out how it's referenced

Comment: if it's not being used as it's supposed to, I guess hand work will have to be :/